# npm install fsevent returns errors

Tags: npm

Hello I'm trying to install fsevent with npm. Therefore I use the following versions:

- Node: 4.2.6
- NPM: 3.5.2
- OS: Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

I'm executing the statement

```
npm install fsevent --no-optional --save react-redux
```

After executing I get the following errors back in the console

```
npm ERR! Linux 4.4.0-45-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install"      
"fsevent"     "--no-optional" "--save" "react-redux"
npm ERR! node v4.2.6
npm ERR! npm  v3.5.2
npm ERR! code E404

npm ERR! 404 Registry returned 404 for GET on     
https://registry.npmjs.org/fsevent
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404  'fsevent' is not in the npm registry.
npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it (or use the name 
yourself!)
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /home/erik/git/test/npm-debug.log
```

Answer (score 1):

it's `fsevents` with an "s" on the end.